# Getting value of variable defined in class

Tags: php, laravel

```
public function showMatch($id){
    $bat_perfo = Cache::remember('bat_1_'.$id, 2, function(){
        return Bat::whereRaw('match_id = ? AND inning = 1', array($id))->get();
    });
    return 0;
}
```

I am getting the error "Undefined variable: id" on line 3

how do i solve this

Comment: our you could pass the $id to the callback function using `... 'bat_1_'.$id, 2, function($id){ ...`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [Reference: What is variable scope, which variables are accessible from where and what are "undefined variable" errors?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16959576/476).

The `function` introduces a new scope, and `$id` is not in scope inside the function. Use `use` to extend its scope:

```
public function showMatch($id){
    $bat_perfo = Cache::remember('bat_1_'.$id, 2, function () use ($id) {
        return Bat::whereRaw('match_id = ? AND inning = 1', array($id))->get();
    });
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add "use" keyword

```
public function showMatch($id){
    $bat_perfo = Cache::remember('bat_1_'.$id, 2, function() use ($id){
        return Bat::whereRaw('match_id = ? AND inning = 1', array($id))->get();
    });
    return 0;
}
```